# How to separate a collection into different "buckets"

Tags: c#

I have a collection of C# objects. Each object has, for data members, a string which is a guid, an index which is an int, and a string which is a document name. Here is what a typical collection looks like:

```
"guid1","c:\temp\doc1.docx",1
"guid1","c:\temp\doc2.docx",2
"guid1","c:\temp\doc3.docx",3
"guid1","c:\temp\doc4.docx",4
"guid2","c:\temp\doc5.docx",5
"guid1","c:\temp\doc6.docx",6
"guid1","c:\temp\doc7.docx",7


I need to end up breaking the collection into individual collections like this:

"guid1","c:\temp\doc1.docx",1
"guid1","c:\temp\doc2.docx",2
"guid1","c:\temp\doc3.docx",3
"guid1","c:\temp\doc4.docx",4


"guid2","c:\temp\doc5.docx",5


"guid1","c:\temp\doc6.docx",6
"guid1","c:\temp\doc7.docx",7
```

These individual collections will then be fed into another function for processing. Trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: What determines where the split happens?

Comment: Could you please define, where the difference is between the first and the third bucket in your example? The GUID is the same.

Comment: Can you add details about your object structure? The data you've shared is CSV and not Object.

Comment: I laid the object out as csv to make it more readable ( or so I hoped ). What determines the split is when the guid changes.

Comment: @KathyLori so an old Guid can appear again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq*, `GroupBy`:

```
 IEnumerable<MyClass> source = ...;

 int group = 0;
 Guid key = new Guid(); 

 // Let's have an array of arrays (array of individual collections) as a result
 MyClass[][] buckets = source
   .GroupBy(item => {
      if (group == 0 || key != item.guid) {
        key = item.guid;
        group += 1; 
      } 

      return group; })
   .Select(chunk => chunk.ToArray()) 
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dmitry. That worked wonderfully. I need to really work on my linq skills.

Comment: @Kathy Lori: you are welcome! Linq indeed is a powerful tool.

Comment: As I look at the answer, it is so much like English and so explicit. I knew linq would be the answer, but how to phrase the answer was the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with linq and no external variables

```
    var list = new []{
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc1.docx", Index = 1},
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc2.docx", Index = 2},
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc3.docx", Index = 3},
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc4.docx", Index = 4},
        new {Id = "guid2", Path = @"c:\temp\doc5.docx", Index = 5},
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc6.docx", Index = 6},
        new {Id = "guid1", Path = @"c:\temp\doc7.docx", Index = 7}
    };


    var batchSize = 3;

    var batched = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.GroupBy(p => p.Index/batchSize)
                                    .ToArray());

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batched);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The json serialization is just for printing to the screen the output, which would be:

```
[
   [
      [
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc1.docx",
            "Index":1
         },
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc2.docx",
            "Index":2
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc3.docx",
            "Index":3
         },
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc4.docx",
            "Index":4
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc6.docx",
            "Index":6
         },
         {
            "Id":"guid1",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc7.docx",
            "Index":7
         }
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         {
            "Id":"guid2",
            "Path":"c:\\temp\\doc5.docx",
            "Index":5
         }
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: The batchsize in my example is 3, but it will be variable.

Comment: Batch size is passed in using `var batchSize = 3;` I meant the count for the items